# What is a Canon Digisuper lens and why is it $200,000+?

Tags: lens, canon

What is this... thing?! And what's so special about it?

http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/887615-REG/Canon_xj100x9_3b_af_lo_XJ100X9_3B_Digital_Zoom_Lens.html

Comment: What is not clear to you in the description that is given in the link you provided?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because, as the description clearly says, this is for HDTV. 

Comment: What's special about it? How about "everything"? Given the specs, I'm amazed that it's so ridiculously cheap!

Comment: Not really off-topic: Sort of a duplicate of this fine question: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/20081/27832

Answer (score 2):

Basically it is so expensive because it is a professional lens for HDTV broadcast video with 100x zoom from 9.3mm out to 930mm (1860mm with a 2x extender) with an f-stop range from 1.7 to 9.4.

It is very hard to compare the specifications of this lens with lenses made for still photography.

From the first page in a search on Google:
http://www.canon.com/bctv/products/digi100af.html

- Extremely high focusing accuracy in full HDTV specifications
- Ability to focus from a completely de-focused status without hunting
- Ability to focus on a high speed moving object
- Size and position of the AF frame (target area) in the camera
- VF can be changed from the Focus Demand FDJ-P31/P41. (The size of the AF Frame can be changed in 3 steps)
- Two operation modes (Full Time AF / Part Time AF) of the Auto Focus system is the answer to a professional camera operator’s various demands.
- Ultra High Zoom ratio 100x
- Ultra Telephoto 1860mm with 2x Ext
- X-Elements & Power Optical System
- Optical Shift Image Stabilaizer
- CAFS (Constant Angle Focusing System)

Comment: "Canon's Tripple Digit Zoom Lens with Auto Focus Function" - all that money on a lens and they still can't spell "triple". :)

Comment: After spending all that money on the lens they had no cash left to pay a subeditor

Comment: Often a name is intentionally misspelled to make it usable as a trademark.  You could not trademark "Triple" but you can with "Tripple(tm)" and now Canon can use "Tripple" across any wide range zoom specialty lenses they make to create a brand.

Comment: Yeah, but what's the bokeh like?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, cinema lenses (such as this) are much more expensive because the focus needs to remain constant when zooming. This is why the Cinema EOS lenses run in the $24k to $75k range.  This is a higher end lens than the Cinema EOS lenses designed for production studio video use on really high end professional cameras and is a very versatile lens, thus very complex. (Long range of focal lengths while maintaining fixed focus during zoom.)  Additionally, this lense provides the feature described as:

CAFS (Constant Angle Focusing System): 32-bit CPU calculates and controls the zoom when focusing to counteract breathing (phenomena where picture size/ angle of view changes when focusing) and has zero zoom effect.

which means that it can also account for the change in zoom when adjusting focus.

Comment: The microeconomist in me says that the reason cinema lenses are much more expensive than photographic lenses is that the people who buy them have much bigger budgets!

Comment: It's actually a *Field* lens intended for broadcast television events such as live sports, not a studio lens. https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/products/list/lenses/broadcast/hdtv-field-box-lenses/hdtv-field-box-lenses